# Stream_get_contents() not working with Cron Job

Tags: php, cron

I have a script called `index.php` "public_html" folder in my host (see below for script content). A cronjob executes the "index.php" file once per minute.

```
$handle = fopen('example.com', 'r');
$source= stream_get_contents($handle);
echo $source;
fclose($handle);
```

The problem is every time "index.php" is executed using the cronjob, `$source` will be '' (an empty string)!

But when I manually execute `index.php` using Firefox and refreshing it's tab, `$source` will be a string including the html source codes of example.com

Is there any restriction settings in my web-host or somewhere else, preventing `stream_get_contects()` to log websites information?

Comment: Is this happening with just any URL or a particular one?

Comment: You said: "when I manually execute index.php using Firefox and refreshing it's tab, `$source` will be a string including the html source codes of example.com" how are you getting `$source` value on the console? Are you writing to a log file? Are you watching the console output? Have you tried executing the script from the CLI?